# Can't create bot using Xcode 6.0.1 due to server certificate validation failure

Tags: xcode6, osx-server

I have upgraded to Xcode 6.0.1 and OSX Server 3.2.1. When I go to setup my bots, I select my shared schema, enter a name, and select my OSX server. When I press next, it validates my source control settings and gives me the following warning:

> Xcode Server ad some issues verifying the credentials for your
>   workspace. Correct or ignore the issues below, and click "Next" to try
>   again.

There is a single issue below, which reads:

> The server certificate failed to verify

What does this error mean, and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to figure this out. Xcode creates a "Code Signing Certificate" when you join the server to your development group. I needed to go into keychain and mark this certificate as "Always Trust". Everything seems to be working after that.

Comment: Worked for me. Had to go to the server and access it's keychain, find the self-signed certificate for the domain, export that and download it to my local machine. Once there I imported the certificate and set it's 'Trust' value to "Always Trust". problem solved.

Comment: I reset to "Always Trust" already, but it is still not working... Are there any other potential errors for causing this issue?